# Rhino Mocks - Mocking a factory

Tags: rhino-mocks, range, collections

I have a factory that creates job objects in the form of IJob

```
Public Interface IJobFactory
    Function CreateJobs(ByVal cacheTypes As CacheTypes) As IEnumerable(Of IJob)
End Interface
```

The interface IJob defines three things

```
Public Interface IJob
    Sub Execute()
    ReadOnly Property Id() As Integer
    ReadOnly Property JobType() As JobType
End Interface
```

I am trying to test the consumer of the factory, a class called JobManager. The job manager calles IJobFactory and asks for the collection of IJobs. I can stub that out just fine but I can't vary the collection size without a lot of work.

Is there a simple way to stub out the collection so that I get a range back?

How can I create a stub of IJobFactory.CreateJobs in such a way that I get back a collection of IJob stubs, say 5 or so where the Id of each of the IJob stubs is different. The ids could be 1 through 5 and that would work great.

Answer (score 1):

I would do create a helper function to set expectations on the factory (c# notation, untested):

```
private List<IJob> SetExpectedJobs(MockRepository mocks, IJobFactory factory, int n)
{
    List<IJob> result = new List<IJob>();
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        IJob job = mocks.CreateStub<IJob>();
        Expect.Call(job.Id).Return(i).Repeat.Any();
        result.Add(job);
    }
    Expect.Call(factory.CreateJobs(null)).Return(result).IgnoreArguments();
    return result;
}
```

and call this function when you set expectation at the beginning of the test. Probably you should pass cacheTypes to this method as well.